# Calculating Percentage of COUNT with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, percentage

Here are the two tables and the only columns that matter for this question.

**Mailing M**
m_id: Id for each of three mailing type

**Mailing Received MR**
u_id: Id for person who received mailing
m_id: FK

I have successfully created this query

```
SELECT 
    m.m_id AS 'Mailing Type',
    COUNT(mr.u_id) AS 'Mailings Received'
FROM mailing m 
Left join
mailing_received mr
ON mr.m_id = m.m_id
GROUP BY m.m_id
```

which returns a table that looks like this

```
Mailing Type     Mailings Received
1                500
2                350
3                600
```

Which is fantastic. Really. But I am trying to return a third column that tells the percentage of the mailings received by mailing type and that is not going as smoothly. Here is what I have tried in a sub query thus far:

```
SELECT
m.m_id,
u_id * 100/ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mailing_received) AS "PERC REC"
FROM mailing m
LEFT JOIN
mailing_received mr
ON
m.m_id = mr.m_id
GROUP BY m.m_id;
```

No dice.

EDIT: `u_id` is sorted into three rows through the COUNT and GROUP BY functions. I have no idea how to create a column of percentages when return rows are divided as such.

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for the issue?

Comment: Just the schema? I can do that.

Comment: I lie. I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    m.m_id AS "Mailing Type",
    COUNT(mr.u_id) AS "Mailings Received",
    COUNT(mr.u_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mailing_received) AS "PERC REC"
FROM mailing m 
Left join mailing_received mr
       ON mr.m_id = m.m_id
GROUP BY m.m_id
```